# FFMPEG: Batch conversion of wmavoice to mp3 without loss of duration or quality

Tags: ffmpeg

I have about 40 wma files that I need to convert to mp3. The content of these files are voice recordings (like notes): just one person speaking, no effects or music or anything else. I managed to convert them to mp3 using ffmpeg on Windows 10, but I faced some issues (listed below) and want help on how to overcome them, please.

#### Here are some details that are relevant to my question:

**ffmpeg tells me the following about the first of the wma files I have:**

```
Audio: wmavoice ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 8000 Hz, mono, flt, 4 kb/s
```

This file has a duration of `00:43:37` and is `1.45MB` in size.

Since all wma files came from the same source, I am assuming they have the similar properties.

**What I tried so far:**

First, using a batch file, I tried the following:

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR %%A IN (%*) DO (
  C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i %%A -aq 5 "%~dp0\wma-to-mp3\%%~nA.mp3"
)
```

The resulting mp3 had the following properties:

```
Audio: mp3, 8000 Hz, mono, s16p, 23 kb/s
```

The file size was `7.37MB`, and - most importantly - did not sound as clear as the original. My friend described it as a bit robotic and noisy (compared to the original wma).

In the second attempt, I tried the following command:

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR %%A IN (%*) DO (
  C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i %%A -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 "%~dp0\wma-to-mp3\%%~nA.mp3"
)
```

The resulting mp3 was nearly the same as the first, with the difference being in size (`9.31MB`) and bitrate (`29 kb/s`). It sounded a lot better, more near to the original wma.

The strange this is, though, that both mp3 have a *shorter* duration than the original file. They both are `00:43:33` long, so five seconds dropped somewhere. I haven't investigated where the drop happened to be honest, as I don't have the time to listen to 43 minutes of audio right now.

However, my friend encouraged me to go with the second option since it sounds good enough, but before doing so I'd like to get help from anyone more experienced with ffmpeg. I am very new to it and have only used it for (successful) simple mp4 and mp3 related commands.

#### So, to sum up the issues:

1. Is it normal for an mp3 made from an wma file to lose seconds during the conversion?
2. Likewise, is the drastic difference in size normal and expected?
3. Are the commands I used the best options for wma files with the properties I mentioned above?
4. Do you know a command that will give me better results?

Thank you for your time.